# How to average every 7 cells without repeating the same cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have a long row of data that I am averaging week-by-week. I would like to grab the first 7 cells with data and be able to drag my formula over so that it grabs the next 7 days of data. Every time that I try this it always grabs the adjacent cell and averages numbers that I have already averaged in the previous formula:

[image: excel sheet]

So what happens is that when I drag to the right it grabs D60:K60 and I want it to grab L60:R60 instead.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: **7** cells, **8** cells or **9** cells? You've mentioned 7 cells and and referred to *a week's data* but C:K from your formula is 9 cells and D:K is 8. Only L:R is 7 cells.

Answer (score 1):

This formula uses `OFFSET` to both stagger and shape the range which is calculated by `AVERAGE`.

`=AVERAGE(OFFSET($C60, 0, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*7, 1, 7))`

Fill right as necessary. It will process `AVERAGE(C60:I60)` then `AVERAGE(J60:P60)`, etc.

**EDIT:**

As `OFFSET` is a *volatile* function that re-calculates whenever any calculation cycle occurs within the workbook, here is a non-volatile equivalent.

`=AVERAGE(INDEX(6:6, 1, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*7+3):INDEX(6:6, 1, (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*7+9))`